# Обработка строки в дату python

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Получаю данные из формы в виде строки '12.12.1990'
как можно ее обработать и отправить в бд?

models

```
class Doc(db.Model):
    dob = db.Column(db.Date)
```

view

```
form = DocForm()
if form.validate_on_submit() and request.method == 'POST':
    dob = request.form['dob']
```

forms

```
class DocForm(FlaskForm):
    dob = DateField('DOB', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Сейчас выдает ошибку

> Incorrect date value: '12.12.1990' for column 'dob' at row 1")

Comment: О какой базе данных идет речь? Что имеется ввиду под обработать (перевести в нужный тип или что-то другое)?

Answer (score 0):

Строку в дату можно перевести с помощью strptime:

```
from datetime import datetime
# ...
dob = datetime.strptime(dob, "%d.%m.%Y")
```